# how to know what type of object that a powershell cmd will return?

Tags: windows, powershell

for example after read Get-Process document i know that Get-Process will return a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process, but how could i know it in cmdline?
is thers some cmd like 'type'?  which will return the function signature of cmd,
like

```
>> type Get-Process
>> Vec<Struct Process {
      BasePriority:String //    Gets the base priority of the associated process.
}>
```

Comment: `Get-Process | Get-Member`

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the `GetType()` method.

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-Process).GetType()                               

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

and additionally the `Get-TypeData` cmdlet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-typedata?view=powershell-7